# Create weekly cumulative totals from R dataframe

Tags: r, database, group-by

I have a dataframe that has launch weeks for products across markets. Here is a snapshot of the dataframe.

```
    Prod_ID        Market_Name         START_WEEK
    11044913000    PHOENIX, AZ         1397
    11044913000    WEST TEX/NEW MEX    1206
    11159402003    PORTLAND,OR         1188
    11159402003    SEATTLE/TACOMA      1188
    11159402003    SPOKANE             1195
    11159410010    PORTLAND,OR         1186
    11159410010    SALT LAKE CITY      1190
    11159410010    SEATTLE/TACOMA      1186
    11159410010    SPOKANE             1187
    11159410010    WEST TEX/NEW MEX    1197
    11159410014    PORTLAND,OR         1198
    11159410014    SEATTLE/TACOMA      1239
```

I would like to create another dataframe which will give me for each `Prod_ID`, cumulative totals of number of markets a product has been launched in on a weekly basis for first 6 weeks. For the above snippet of data, the output should like something like this.

```
    Prod_ID        Week1    Week2    Week3    Week4    Week5    Week6
    11044913000    1        1        1        1        1        1
    11159402003    2        2        2        2        2        2
    11159410010    2        3        3        3        4        4
    11159410014    1        1        1        1        1        1
```

For ease of displaying, I have shown the output only till Week 6, but I need to track till Week 12 for my need. Week is denoted by a 4 digit number in my dataset and is not in date format. Please note that not all products have the same starting week, so I need to infer the earliest week for a `Prod_ID`from the `START_WEEK` variable. And then identify the next 6 weeks to generate the total number of markets launched in each week.

Any help to do this is appreciated.

Comment: How are you translating from `START_WEEK` to `Week#`?

Comment: @r2evans - I have to create those columns. For example, for Prod_ID 11159410010, I will choose START_WEEK 1186 as Week1 for that product, 1187 is Week2 and so on. Likewise, for Prod_ID 11159402003, 1188 will be Week1, 1189 Week2 and so on. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Uh, ok. Does that mean that (a) the first row suggests a column named `Week213`?, and (b) you are expecting a frame with over 200 columns? I know you say *"track till Week 12"*, but there appears to be some unstated assumptions. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: There are 5 markets where Prod_ID 11159410010. Why are there only 4 indicated in Week 6? Also, there are only 4 unique start weeks for this Prod_ID.

Comment: @r2evans - I am not clear about part (a) in your question. For part (b), while one can track the count of markets till over 200 weeks (that's what hpesoj626 's proposed solution does), what I meant is that I am interested in looking at only the first 12 weeks since launch for each product.

Comment: @hpesoj626 - I think you got my problem. I didn't know we could use group_by and ungroup the way you have done, so that's new learning for me. I still need to understand the phase 3 that you have proposed, but your solution does what I wanted to do. I am accepting your answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. Here is my shot. There are several phases to this solution.

The first step is to calculate the cumulative sum of markets for the weeks and the week number for each `Prod_ID` since they opened. This is done with the following code chunk.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Prod_ID, START_WEEK) %>%
  count() %>%
  arrange(Prod_ID, START_WEEK) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Prod_ID) %>%
  mutate(tot_market = cumsum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Prod_ID) %>%
  mutate(min_START_WEEK = min(START_WEEK)) %>%
  mutate(week = START_WEEK - min_START_WEEK + 1) 
df1

# # A tibble: 10 x 6
# # Groups:   Prod_ID [4]
#         Prod_ID START_WEEK     n tot_market min_START_WEEK  week
#           <dbl>      <int> <int>      <int>          <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 11044913000.       1206     1          1          1206.    1.
#  2 11044913000.       1397     1          2          1206.  192.
#  3 11159402003.       1188     2          2          1188.    1.
#  4 11159402003.       1195     1          3          1188.    8.
#  5 11159410010.       1186     2          2          1186.    1.
#  6 11159410010.       1187     1          3          1186.    2.
#  7 11159410010.       1190     1          4          1186.    5.
#  8 11159410010.       1197     1          5          1186.   12.
#  9 11159410014.       1198     1          1          1198.    1.
# 10 11159410014.       1239     1          2          1198.   42.
```

The second phase is to expand the `week` and `Prod_ID` to the maximum number of weeks in `week`.

```
df2 <- expand.grid(min(df1$week):max(df1$week), unique(df1$Prod_ID))
colnames(df2) <- c("week", "Prod_ID")
```

The third phase is done by merging `df1` and `df2` and using `zoo::locf` to fill the `NA`'s in `tot_market` (total market) by `Prod_ID` with the preceding value.

```
df2 %>% left_join(df1) %>% select(-START_WEEK, -n, -min_START_WEEK) %>%
  group_by(Prod_ID) %>%
  arrange(Prod_ID, week) %>%
  mutate(tot_market = zoo::na.locf(tot_market)) %>%
  spread(week, tot_market) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Prod_ID), as.character) %>%
  rename_if(is.integer, function(x) paste0("Week", x))

# # A tibble: 4 x 193
#   Prod_ID     Week1 Week2 Week3 Week4 Week5 Week6 Week7 Week8 Week9 Week10 Week11
#   <chr>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 11044913000     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1
# 2 11159402003     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     3     3      3      3
# 3 11159410010     2     3     3     3     4     4     4     4     4      4      4
# 4 11159410014     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1      1
# # ... with 181 more variables
```